# Visual Studio delays when Start Without Debugging on a console application

Tags: visual-studio

Recently my Visual Studio started to experience a delay before the program Starts Without Debugging.

This happens only when the following are met:

- Console application
- Start Without Debugging
- There has been any change in the editor window from the last time program run.

After pressing Ctrl+F5 console application window opens and the cursor is active, but the execution is delayed.

The delay seems to be consistent in length (7-10 seconds), and not depend on the size of the code. I have checked two different installations of VS (2013 and 2015) on the same computer and the problem persists.

I have also checked that this delay occurs even for an empty Main().

There is a possibility that I have enabled some kind of an option/function in VS that causes this very specific delay, but I am not sure when this issue started occurring so I cannot trace back the change.

What could be the reason for this delay?

I will be grateful for help in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made many attempts to diagnose the issue of the delay and one of the times that I pressed ctrl + F5 I have spotted a window opening in the background. 
(It was definitely not visible everytime i tried to run without debugging).

It turns out that  a functionality of Avira anti-virus had been scanning the code before it run for the first time. That is why when I made no changes to the code there was no delay.

Avira "Protection Cloud" is the name of the functionality responsible for the delays.
Link to Avira page about it and how to disable it: https://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/1514

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if I have multiple editting windows open, this slows starting and stopping the debugger. Close all but those you are interested in and try again.